# How to add second layer with different sizes in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm using OpenLayers 3 for deep-zooming into high resolution images (no geo-coordinates, only pixels).

And *XYZ* is the format that I need as projection, but I have a problem with adding one more tiled layer, because it should have different projection.
I.e. my main layer has sizes (X) x (Y) in pixels, but second layer has sizes (X * k) x (Y * k). Therefore the layers don't correspond to each other. The tile size is the same in both cases.

Here is the code:

```
const imWidth = 100440;
const imHeight = 221312;

const primaryImageProjection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'PIXELS',
  units: 'pixels',
  extent: [0, 0, imWidth, imHeight],
  getPointResolution: function (resolution, point) {
    return resolution;
  }
});
ol.proj.addProjection(primaryImageProjection);

var heatMapProj = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'HEATMAP',
  units: 'pixels',
  extent: [0, 0, imWidth, imWidth],
  getPointResolution: function (resolution, point) {
    return resolution;
  }
});
ol.proj.addProjection(heatMapProj);

const koef = 21.5;
ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms('PIXELS', 'HEATMAP',
  function (coordinate) {
    return [coordinate[0] * koef, coordinate[1] * koef];
  },
  function (coordinate) {
    return [coordinate[0] / koef, coordinate[1] / koef];
  });

this.map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        crossOrigin: crossOrigin,
        tileSize: [512, 512],
        tileUrlFunction: (tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) => {
          const tileUrlTemplate = 'http://.../?lvl={z}&tx={x}&ty={y}';
          const z = 9 - tileCoord[0];
          const tileUrl = tileUrlTemplate
            .replace("{z}", (z).toString())
            .replace("{x}", (tileCoord[1]).toString())
            .replace("{y}", (((-tileCoord[2]) - 1)).toString());
          return tileUrl;
        },
        projection: 'PIXELS'
      })
    }),
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        crossOrigin: crossOrigin,
        tileSize: [512, 512],
        tileUrlFunction: (tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) => {
          const heatMapUrlTemplate = 'http://...?lvl={z}&tx={x}&ty={y}';
          var z = 4 - tileCoord[0];
          const heatMapUrl = heatMapUrlTemplate
            .replace('{z}', (z).toString())
            .replace('{x}', (tileCoord[1]).toString())
            .replace('{y}', (((-tileCoord[2]) - 1)).toString());
          return heatMapUrl;
        },
        projection: 'HEATMAP'
      }),
      opacity: 0.5
    })
  ],
  controls: [],
  target: this.mapSelector,
  renderer: "canvas",
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'PIXELS'
  })
});
```

How can I solve this? Maybe projections are not the right way and it can be solved differently.

PS: also you can see that I'm using the function getPointResolution. Otherwise I see error messages in console: "transform should be defined". And after dubugging I found that OpenLayers makes some transformations internally from my projections into "EPSG:4326" and back. I wouldn't expect to have any spherical coordinates inside, since I'm using only flat images, but it looks that OpenLayers need it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Raster reprojection (i.e. different projections for the layers of a map) is not an experimental feature. But to make it work for you, you need to register transformation functions between the projections of your layers, using `ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms`. Without seeing your code it is hard to guess, but something like this should do the trick:

```
var proj1 = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'ZOOMIFY1',
  units: 'pixels',
  extent: [0, -Y, X, 0]
});
var proj2 = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'ZOOMIFY2',
  units: 'pixels',
  extent: [0, -Y * k, X * k, 0]
});

ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms(proj1, proj2,
    function(coordinate) {
      return [coordinate[0] * k, coordinate[1] * k];
    },
    function(coordinate) {
      return [coordinate[1] / k, coordinate[2] / k];
    });
```

Now you can go ahead, configure your two Zoomify layers - the first with `proj1` as projection and the second with `proj2`, and they should align just fine.

Note that the above is untested. If you can provide a working snippet or JSFiddle, I can refine my answer if something is not working.

Comment: Thanks! I added the code and meanwhile switched from Zoomify to XYZ.
Unfortunately JSFIddle-sample is problematic, because the sources for images are internal. 
And addCoordinateTransforms doesn't produce right picture to me even if I use k=1. Images are still not aligned.

Comment: Hi once again! I've prepared jsfiddle for this case https://jsfiddle.net/x3jdc1kr/ 
Could you take a look? The numbers on the tiles correspond to the current zooming level.